# PHP - Find and Replace of JSON data

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to do a find replace of the json data below. I'm trying to replace "Consumer" with "CON", "Industrial" with "IND", and "Technology" with "TCH". Ideally, I would like to pass a function an array of finds (i.e., {"Consumer", "Industrial", "Technology"}) along with an array of replaces (i.e., {"CON", "IND", "TCH"}), or some other way to quickly define multiple find and replace pairs (there will be many more pairs than these 3). What is the best function to do this? Thanks, any help is appreciated.

```
[{"category":"Consumer","price":"18.9","number":"5"},{"category":"Industrial","price":"13.4","number":"4"},{"category":"Technology","price":"15.5","number":"3"}]
```

Comment: Your best bet would be to json_decode, loop over the data, do a proper replace of the string and then just json_encode back instead of trying to modify the json itself. From reading the structure, that wouldn't be much work either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a solution that goes through the json data object piece by piece (examining both key and values and replacing as possible only if the key/value is fully in the array of `$replaces`)

```
function replace(&$array, $replaces) {
    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
        $new_k = replace_word($k, $replaces);
        if (is_array($v)) {
            replace($v, $replaces);
        }
        else {
            $v = replace_word($v, $replaces);
        }
        $array[$new_k] = $v;
        if ($new_k != $k) {
            unset($array[$k]);
        }
    }
}

function replace_word($word, $replaces) {
    if (array_key_exists($word, $replaces)) {
        $word = str_replace($word, $replaces[$word], $word);
    }
    return $word;
}

/* TEST FUNCTIONS */
$json = '[{"category":"Consumer","price":"18.9","number":"5"},{"category":"Industrial","price":"13.4","number":"4"},{"category":"Technology","price":"15.5","number":"3"}]';

$replaces = array("category" => "cat", "Consumer" => "cons");
$json_data = json_decode($json, true);
var_dump($json_data);
replace($json_data, $replaces);
var_dump($json_data);
$json = json_encode($json_data);
```

Answer (score -1):

`preg_replace` can take pattern and replacement as arrays.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

So, for example:

`preg_replace(array('Consumer', 'Industrial', 'Technology'), array('CON', 'IND', 'TCH'), $json);`

Note, however, that unless you're absolutely sure of the JSON you'll be getting it is probably better practice to parse the JSON and replace within the actual key/values.

Comment: String in JSON is prefixed by length, you should modify length too!